# Calculating higher Order Moments and concentration

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Are there some easier ways to calculate higher order moments of sum of random variables? In particular we are trying to use Chernoff type inequalities to prove concentration bound on the following random variable for which we need to prove bounds on higher order moments.

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be ordered sets with n elements each. Let $A \subset S_1$ and $B \subset S_2$ with sizes $a$ and $b$ respectively. Let X be a random variable denoting number of edges between set A and set B if we chose a random matching between elements of A and elements of

How do we calculate or prove bounds on $E[(X-\mu)^t]$.